# switch interface for translating

Tags: i18n-l10n

I'm currently working on a multi lingual site that contains 2 languages. (EN & DE)

Most nodes are translated, but when I edit an DE node, my interface remains in EN, which leads to some very weird stuff happening when you save, some of the node references disappear. (Because they are in another language)

In my configuration 'Switch interface for translating' is switched on, but it still doesn't switch when editing a node in another language.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Are you in D6 or D7?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, this is D7